# Can the list command in a Symfony Console app be disabled?

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony console, and I'd like to disable the list command so it's not shown in the help output. The list of commands is shown in the help command anyway. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extend the symfony Application you are using in your script (usually `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application`) and override the `getDefaultCommands` method:

```php
protected function getDefaultCommands()
{
    // Original:
    // return [ new HelpCommand(), new ListCommand() ];

    return [ new HelpCommand() ];
}
```

and then use that class in your `bin/console` script

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these instructions to hide a specific command
https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/hide_commands.html

Quoted from their documentation:

> Hidden commands behave the same as normal commands but they are no longer displayed in command listings, so end-users are not aware of their existence.

Comment: Ah, yes, I can hide my own commands; it's the built-in list command I'd like to stop appearing!

Comment: Please check this, I think it's similar to what you're looking for
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58599844/how-to-hide-or-delete-the-defaults-available-console-commands

Comment: Even that very basic setup, with a single user-created command, also has the list command provided by Symfony Console. I'm looking for a way to disable that built-in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build on Allessandro's answer and use the document provided by Wajdi to extend the ListCommand and Application classes so that I could just hide the list command, which it turned out was more useful than completely disabling it.

```php
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\ListCommand as SymfonyListCommand;

class ListCommand extends SymfonyListCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        parent::configure();
        $this->setHidden(true);
    }
}
```

```php
use App\Console\ListCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application as SymfonyApplication;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\HelpCommand;

class Application extends SymfonyApplication
{
    protected function getDefaultCommands()
    {
        return [new HelpCommand(), new ListCommand()];
    }
}
```